# Insider Fast Ring fails to install since 15048, is there a log

Tags: windows-insider

Since 15048, I can't upgrade to the latest insider fast ring.  No changes to hardware / software, but it's a rather limited system: 2GB ram, old HP system, running 32-bit OS.  Not sure what type of CPU.

Is there an upgrade log that I can read to determine the cause of the failure?

Comment: log is in C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\panther: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/928901/log-files-that-are-created-when-you-upgrade-to-a-new-version-of-windows

Comment: ok, I posted an answer with an addition link with a list of errors.

Comment: any update? was my answer helpful?

Comment: Note: Late May 2017, the insider builds started to work again.  I have no idea what the issue was in the end.

Comment: ok, nice to hear that it worked now. Next time you know how to analyze the logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [log files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/928901/log-files-that-are-created-when-you-upgrade-to-a-new-version-of-windows) are located under `C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\panther`.

> The following log files are created when an upgrade fails, and the
>   installation rollback is initiated:
>
> C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\Rollback\setupact.log
>   C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\Rollback\setupact.err

MS [lists here all errors and possible fixes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3107983).

So open the `C:\Windows\panther\setuperr.log` to see what is failed and look in the list what the error means and how you can solve it.